# Create a Report with different pages style using Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to make a report, and I have chosen JasperReport to create it. I want to make up a report that in each Page contains different summary. Example:

- page 1: it will appear the table of contents
- Page 2: A table with information
- Page 3: Images, etc.

Could it be possible done with JasperReport? I saw the Table of Contents example of jasper report and I can't understand it with any documentation.
If someone have done an example like I explained above, please contact me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking JRXML file. layout can be determined using jrxml files. I suggest to use itext which allows you to have full control on writing into a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Without further thinking or trying, I would say make 3 groups. Each one has a `Print When Expression`

For the first group it will be something like `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1` and so on.`